# How to use Matlab to make a heat map with values given by coordinates from Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, heatmap

```
data = xlsread('excel.xlsx');
x = linspace(min(data(:,5)),max(data(:,5)),150);
y = linspace(min(data(:,6)),max(data(:,6)),150);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

F=TriScatteredInterp(data(:,5),data(:,6)-1);
contourf(X,Y,F(X,Y),150,'LineColor','none')
```

> Error: Error using TriScatteredInterp
> The input points must be 2D or 3D coordinates in numpoints-by-ndim format.
>
> Error in testing (line 6):
> F=TriScatteredInterp(data(:,5),data(:,6)-1);

I wish to plot the heatmap from 2 column of data from excel. What other method can be used to construct a heat map as shown below?Any help is appreciated.

[image: Heat Map Image]

Comment: what does `data` looks like? Can you post an example to reproduce your problem?

Comment: data look like the most frequent points are concentrating in the middle

Comment: Note that you better use [`scatteredinterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) instead.

Comment: The error is quite clear, it says `TriScatteredInterp` expects a 2D or 3D input, but you give `data(:,5)` and `data(:,6)` which are both vectors (`size(data,1)`-by-1).

Comment: I only have a column of data for x and another column data for y . Not sure how to make use of only 2 column of data to form heat map. Alot of info given online are mostly in x,y,z.